# Modelling two correlated variables

Tags: regression, time-series, modeling, mutual-information

I wish to simultaneously predict two correlated time series. Here is a plot of one time series against the other:

[image: Correlated Variables]

At the moment I have separate linear regressions for both of them which rely on some IVs and while performance is acceptable I'd like to find some way to take account of the relationship between them when making forecasts.

Can anyone suggest strategies that do this? I'm working in python mostly so anything that is already implemented in python is a bonus!

Comment: What do you mean by "making predictions" - do you have a value of one of the variables and want to predict the other; or do you need to predict both variables simultaneously?  Or is there a time series element?

Comment: I've added the time-series tag to make it more visible to the specialists in that area.  As well as modelling the two series together, there will be significant improvements on a linear regression even for just one series.  Any chance you could add a traditional time series plot of each series? - it's not possible to see trend or seasonality in the scatter plot.

Comment: And the other basic plots to see would be the autocorrelation function plot for the residuals of each of your regressions; and the cross correlation function plot of the two.  These things are possible in Python but you'd find it much easier to do in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regress `Y` on `X` and find `Rsquared` and `Dubin-Watson statistic`. If former is greater than later, then it indicates spurious correlation. If this is the case, you can proceed as follows:

1. Check whether each variable has an unit root. If both variables have the unit root, then the correlation that you are saying may be spurious.
2. If both don't have unit root, you can proceed with the usual OLS model.
3. If both are unit root, you need to proceed for estimating whether two variables are cointegrated (move together in the long run).
4. If both have unit root and there is no cointegration, then use VAR model.

Use standard text books on time series for details. For example, applied time series econometrics by [Walter Enders](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470505397).

I am not the user of `Python` but looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996021/packages-for-time-series-forecasting) post, it seems that `python` lags `R` in terms of time series analysis.